# Pattern Matching with PowerShell 1

Tags: windows, powershell

All,

I am new to Windows admin-type stuff but I am familiar with Unix/Linux, etc. I have a simple PowerShell 1 script that should only copy files that match this naming convention:

```
Daily_Reviews[1099-9987].journal
```

My pattern in $source is causing errors: "Could not find part of the path.." Need to know how to do pattern matching in the PowerShell environment I guess

Here is my code:

```
$source = "C:\Users\Tom\Daily_Reviews\[\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d\]\.journal" 
$destination ="C:\Users\Tom\Processed\"

if(-not(Test-Path $destination)){mkdir $destination | out-null}

  Copy-Item $source $destination
```

Comment: Can you clarify, PS1 is the extension, but the host may not be version 1 -- What's the output of `$PSVersionTable`?

Comment: That variable doesn't exist. I also personally installed PowerShell v1 today. There was nothing on this machine prior so I am pretty sure it's version1

Comment: As an fyi these type of questions might be better answered in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -match for instance `if ( "$source" -match "Daily_Reviews*" ) { echo Match! }`

This accepts regex.

What you are trying to do should probably be done with a for loop anyhow, like for example

ls Daily_Reviews* > file.txt ; get-content file.txt while read input, do a copy, etc...

(I'm not a powershell guy)

Answer (score 0):

You might try something more like this:

```
$source = Join-Path "C:\Users" $env:username
$destination = Join-Path $source "Processed"

if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($destination)) {[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($destination)}

dir -Path $source -file -filter "*.journal" | where { $_ -match "Daily_Reviews\d{4}" } | ForEach-Object { Move-Item -Path $_.fullname -Destination $destination }
```

However, this might not work in PS1. It might be worth upgrading to Powershell 2?

This was assuming that you were looking to transfer more than one file - you could have equally populated an array with the different potential names of files, and checked each individually, but creating the variable as you did won't work (to my knowledge).